# Local NodeJS app works but when deployed to PLESK server it doesn't

Tags: node.js, subdomain, plesk

I have the followin node js app that works perfectly locally, but not in the server. To be more specific it's deployed in a subdomain and in a subfolder of httpdocs.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Define the MQTT broker options
const options = {
    port: process.env.MQTT_PORT,
    username: process.env.MQTT_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.MQTT_PASSWORD,
    clientId: `mqttjs_${Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)}`,
    protocol: "wss",
};

// Define the MQTT broker address and topic
const broker = process.env.MQTT_BROKER;
const topic = process.env.MQTT_TOPIC;

// Connect to the MQTT broker
const client = mqtt.connect(broker, options);

// Initialize to 4 minutes ago Τελευταία εισαγωγή στη βάση
let lastInsertTime = Date.now() - 4 * 60 * 1000;

// Initialize the last received message
let lastMessage = null;

// Initialize countdown
let countdown = 4 * 60; // 3 minutes in seconds

// Initialize message and DB insert counts
let messageCount = 0;
let dbInsertCount = 0;

// Set up a new MySQL connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Failed to connect to the database:", err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});

client.on("connect", function () {
    client.subscribe(topic, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Successfully subscribed to the topic");
        }
    });
});

let lastReceivedMessageTime = Date.now();
let noData = false;

let countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (countdown > 0 && !noData) {
        countdown--;
        const minutes = Math.floor(countdown / 60);
        const seconds = countdown % 60;
        console.log(
            `Time remaining until next insert: ${minutes} minutes and ${seconds} seconds`
        );
    } else {
        clearInterval(countdownInterval);
    }
}, 1000);

client.on("message", function (topic, message) {
    lastReceivedMessageTime = Date.now();
    noData = false;

    messageCount++;
    lastMessage = message;

    console.log("Received message:", message.toString());

    // Reset the countdown only if needed
    if (Date.now() - lastInsertTime >= 4 * 60 * 1000 && lastMessage) {
        countdown = 4 * 60; // Reset the countdown
        const data = JSON.parse(lastMessage.toString());

        let sql = "INSERT INTO `vivus02` SET ?";
        let dataObj = {};
        data.d.forEach((item) => {
            dataObj[item.tag] = item.value;
        });
        dataObj.timestamp = data.ts;

        connection.query(sql, dataObj, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("Failed to insert data into the database:", error);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Data successfully inserted into the database");

            dbInsertCount++;
            lastInsertTime = Date.now();
            lastMessage = null;
        });
    }
});

// // Start the countdown
// let countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
//  if (countdown > 0) {
//      countdown--;
//  }
//  if (noData) {
//      clearInterval(countdownInterval); // Stop the countdown if no data is available
//  } else {
//      // Calculate minutes and seconds
//      const minutes = Math.floor(countdown / 60);
//      const seconds = countdown % 60;

//      // Print the countdown
//      console.log(
//          `Time remaining until next insert: ${minutes} minutes and ${seconds} seconds`
//      );
//  }
// }, 10000);

process.on("exit", (code) => {
    console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`);
});

// Set up Express.js server
const app = express();

// Serve static files from the current directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
console.log(__dirname);

// Use body-parser middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

setInterval(() => {
    if (Date.now() - lastReceivedMessageTime > 2 * 60 * 1000) {
        // No data if no messages in the last 2 minutes
        noData = true;
    }
}, 2 * 60 * 1000);

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        messageCount,
        dbInsertCount,
        tableName: "vivus02",
        mqttTopic: topic,
        nextInsertTime: lastInsertTime + 4 * 60 * 1000, // Send the time of the next insert operation
        noData,
    });
});

/// Use body-parser middleware to parse JSON requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Define a route to handle table creation requests
app.post("/createTable", (req, res) => {
    // Extract table name and JSON string from the request body
    const { table, jsonString } = req.body;

    try {
        // Parse the JSON string into a JavaScript object
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        // Extract data array from JSON object
        const data = jsonData.d;

        // Extract tags and their corresponding value types from the data array
        const columns = data.map((item) => {
            const value = item.value;
            const valueType = typeof value;
            let dataType;
            switch (valueType) {
                case "string":
                    dataType = "VARCHAR(255)";
                    break;
                case "number":
                    if (Number.isInteger(value)) {
                        dataType = "INT";
                    } else {
                        dataType = "DECIMAL(10, 2)";
                    }
                    break;
                case "boolean":
                    dataType = "BOOLEAN";
                    break;
                default:
                    dataType = "VARCHAR(255)";
            }
            return { tag: item.tag, dataType: dataType };
        });

        // Connect to the MySQL database
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
        });

        // Define the SQL query to create the table
        let createTableQuery = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${table} (
                    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    ts DATETIME`;

        // Loop through the columns and add them as columns to the table
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            createTableQuery += `,
                    ${column.tag} ${column.dataType}`;
        });

        // Close the SQL query
        createTableQuery += ")";

        // Execute the SQL query
        connection.query(createTableQuery, (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) {
                // If an error occurs, send an error response
                console.error("Failed to create table:", error);
                res
                    .status(500)
                    .json({ success: false, message: "Failed to create table" });
            } else {
                // If the table is created successfully, send a success response
                console.log("Table created successfully");
                res
                    .status(200)
                    .json({ success: true, message: "Table created successfully" });
            }
            // Close the MySQL connection
            connection.end();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // If an error occurs during JSON parsing, send an error response
        console.error("Failed to parse JSON string:", error);
        res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Invalid JSON string" });
    }
});

//CREATE TABLE END

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

I really don't know what to do... I've tried everything

I think that something has to do with the routes/paths of the subdomain. In nodejs logs I don't get any errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it's deployed in a subdomain and in a subfolder of httpdocs.*"? This is a nodejs application that hasn't to do anything with httpdocs. You mean you deployed the frontend of this application to that folder? Does the frontend show up when you try to access it? Does your server's firewall allow connections on port 3000?

Comment: Does a minimal app work? It doesn’t seem like this is related to the code yet—but we don’t know what you’ve tried.